# The attribute "Version" in element <PackageReference> is unrecognized

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild, .net-standard

I have a solution with many projects that target .net 4.6.1. On our MS build server it builds just fine. I recently added a project that targets .NET Standard 1.3. This will not build on the build server. It builds locally with VS2017 just fine. Build server VS has just been updated with all the latest.

The build error I'm getting is: `The attribute "Version" in element <PackageReference> is unrecognized.`

I am getting this for a few references. Here's one pulled from the project file: `<PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.Process" Version="4.3.0"/>`

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably an MSBuild version mismatch. Your build server likely needs a more recent version.

Comment: Build Engine version 15.9.21 is what's on the machine

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I encountered this issue in my Xamarin forms build pipeline

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I did get this working (my notes suggest I abandoned this with no fix). But I never tried Bhatt's answer.

Answer (score 13):

Looks like you are not building using the MSBuild.exe that is included in VS 2017 (/ build tools) but rather the MSBuild.exe that ships with .NET Framework, which is an old version (and won't be updated).

Consider using [VSWhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere) to locate MSBuild.exe

Comment: This looks promising, however I don't know how to get the build server to actually use the new MSBuild. I'm not sure where VSWhere fits into the picture. I'm creating build definitions in VS and kicking off the build that way. Further, I can't imagine why I'd have to resort to using VSWhere when I simply want to use the latest MSBuild. I clearly have an imcomplete picture of how this process works.

Comment: Depends on what you use as build server.. TFS has tasks for builds using recent VS versions for example (unless you're using XAML builds but they are deprecated anyway)

Comment: thanks! this was it, in my case the project I was trying to build uses Cake, so I had to do some tweaking to change the default MSBuild path this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45251462/544947

Answer (score 11):

If anyone come across this thread, refer below solution for .Net Framework projects.

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.Process">
    <Version>4.3.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

Comment: thanks, this solution works for visual studio 2015!

Answer (score 3):

I was getting that same build error message using  **NuGet Version: 3.4.4.1321**

I ran `nuget update -self`

```
Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 3.4.4-rtm-1321.
Updating NuGet.exe to 5.1.0.
Update successful.
```

and afterwards there was no longer a build error when I ran nuget

Comment: In my case, nuget is up to date, at v5.1.0 and I still get the error

Answer (score 1):

The right version of MSBuild is needed to build a project file with package references with version attribute. From Team City this screen shot shows an example. Note the name, 'Microsoft Build Tools 2017'. This is the package you want to have on your developer PC or target server.

[image: Team City - Select MSBuild Version]

This will be helpful for the CI /devops / build people out there that needs to build .NET applications / other apps requiring MSbuild on a build server.